# the current position value is stale in viewpager getCurrentItem method

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have view pager to show the data day by day. And I set the current item position. here is coding..

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new DashboardViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), selectedDate);

    daoManager = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DAOManager.class);

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    Date d = pagerAdapter.getDate(365);
    Log.i("pageAdapter", d.toString());

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(365);
    Log.i("viewAdapter", viewPager.getCurrentItem()+"");

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg) {

        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Date d = pagerAdapter.getDate(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            monthTitleTextView.setText(formatter.format(d));
            selectedDate = d;
            Log.i("onPageSelected", selectedDate.toString());
            Log.i("onPageSelected", viewPager.getCurrentItem()+"");
        }

    });
```

And I have `onSaveInstanceState` method to store the `selectedDate`.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(DAOManager.SELECTED_DATE, selectedDate);
    Log.i("onSaveInstanceState", selectedDate.toString());
}
```

I run the coding, I got this result.

```
08-02 13:03:17.868: I/pageAdapter(16770): Fri Aug 02 00:00:00
 GMT+06:30 2013 08-02 13:03:17.868: I/viewAdapter(16770): 365
```

And I slide for one day. I got this result.

```
08-02 13:07:17.278: I/onPageSelected(16770): Sat Aug 03 00:00:00
GMT+06:30 2013 08-02 13:07:17.278: I/onPageSelected(16770): 366
```

After that I rotate the screen to change orientation. The result is like this.

```
08-02 13:10:27.558: I/onSaveInstanceState(16770): Sat Aug 03 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2013
08-02 13:10:27.748: I/dateList (16770): 731 from Fri Aug 03 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2012-- to Sun Aug 03 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2014
08-02 13:10:27.748: I/pageAdapter(16770): Sat Aug 03 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2013
08-02 13:10:27.748: I/viewAdapter(16770): 365
08-02 13:10:27.888: I/onPageSelected(16770): Sun Aug 04 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2013
08-02 13:10:27.888: I/onPageSelected(16770): 366
```

My problem is that after the screen orientation change, the current item position is stale even I set the position in the `oncreate` method. I would like to know how to refresh the current item position of view pager.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way not to call the `onPageSelected` after the screen orientation is change?

Comment: pls any one help me!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this, It may help you

```
 mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(SampleCirclesWithListener.this, "Changed to page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I tried, But the position is `366`. It should be `365`. `getCurrentItem()` method and `position` return same value.